# How to fix git path after MacOS Sierra update?

Tags: git, macos, intellij-idea, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I have just upgraded from OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" to 10.12: "Sierra", and when I open intellijIdea, I get the following error:

Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git
            Probably the path to Git executable is not valid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My problem resolved after running xcode installation with following code from terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Following most upgrades on macOS you generally need to upgrade to latest Xcode and reinstall all the dev /command line tools it will fix most issues.

Answer (score 1):

just open xcode then  xcode will ask you to accept new agreement press accept and then the problem will be solved

Answer (score 1):

In recent MacOS updates the git path is :

**/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.16.2/bin/git**

Instead of 2.16.2 Choose your version